# Rounding Approximation for Blackbox Integer Optimization

Tags: experiment-design, gaussian-process, bayesian-optimization

I am working on a black-box optimization that involves surrogate modeling. Some of my decision variables are integers, but I doubt a MIP approach would work for my case.

My advisor told me that it is okay to treat these variables as continuous values for now, as this makes it easier to build surrogate models. After obtaining optimal values, we can simply approximate integer results by rounding.

I doubt this is frequently used in academia, but does anybody know any rigorous proof to back up this heuristic?

EDIT: I am using Gaussian process as my surrogate model. A sample-then-optimize approach will be used, using expected improvement of the Gaussian process.

More EDIT: This is for hyperparameter tuning. In each iteration, a set of hyperparameters will be used for a specific ML model. A sample of prediction metric (accuracy, MSE, etc.) will be taken and fed into GP. Then we use EI to find the next set of hyperparameters to try.

Comment: Hi, can you provide a little bit more detail on your setup? In particular, what kind of surrogate model are you worried won't like integers? At what point are you suggesting rounding? What kind of acquisition do you have in mind?

Comment: Glad to hear that it's the classic GP-EI combo. What is a sample-then-optimize approach?

Comment: Thanks for your edits. I'm a little confused because you mention several predictions metrics, but also EI, which is appropriate for scalar, rather than multi-output, situations. But anyways, you ask for "rigorous proof". These tend not to be particularly useful in BO, where finite sample and minimal assumptions are king. I hope you'll instead accept a reference to this '22 neurips article (https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper_files/paper/2022/file/531230cfac80c65017ad0f85d3031edc-Paper-Conference.pdf), which has numerical experiments...

Comment: ...finding that rounding works pretty well both in terms of best observed function value as well as in compute time on a variety of problems. (If I understand your situation correctly, it is the method they refer to as "CONT. RELAX").

Comment: @JohnMadden That is an interesting reference, thanks for the reply! And yes, I am only optimizing one prediction metric in each experiment, but such metrics can be accuracy, MSE, or some others.

Comment: @JohnMadden Thank you! Checked out some of your work in this area, and I think they will be very helpful for my project.